# What is the correct way to implement derived classes with arbitrary combinations of common virtual function implementations?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

What is the correct way to implement a set of derived classes with different combinations of common member function implementations without copying code? The classes `W`, `X`, `Y`, and `Z` all derive from class `base` because they need to be able access member variables in the base class.

I know of a way to do it with diamond inheritance, but I suspect there is a better way.

```
class base {
      virtual void f() { /* implementation f_0 */ }
      virtual void g() { /* implementation g_0 */ }
      virtual void h() { /* implementation h_0 */ }
  };

 class W : public base {
      void g() override { /* implementation g_1 */ }
  };

  class X : public base {
      void g() override { /* implementation g_1 */ }
      void h() override { /* implementation h_1 */ }
  };

  class Y : public base {
      void f() override { /* implementation f_1 */ }
      void h() override { /* implementation h_1 */ }
  };

  class Z : public base {
      void f() override { /* implementation f_1 */ }
      void h() override { /* implementation h_2 */ }
  };
```

Comment: Do the virtual functions have to be pure virtual? Could the `*_0` implementations just be default implementations of the functions?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried updating the example to improve it, but I guess it will probably get closed from the negative votes.

Answer (score 1):

Use intermediate class with default implementation:

```
class base {
public:
    virtual ~base() = default;
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual void g() = 0;
    virtual void h() = 0;
};

class derived : public base {
    void f() override { /* implementation f_0 */ }
    void g() override { /* implementation g_0 */ }
    void h() override { /* implementation h_0 */ }
};


class X : public derived {
    void g() override { /* implementation g_1 */ }
};

class Y : public derived {
    void f() override { /* implementation f_1 */ }
};

class Z : public derived {
    void h() override { /* implementation h_1 */ }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried updating the example to improve it, but I guess the question will probably get closed from the negative votes.

Answer (score 1):

Marc Gregoire discusses this topic in chapter 10 of [Professional C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119421306).

Here is a way to do this with diamond inheritance.

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  struct base {
      virtual void f() { cout << "f_0\n"; /* implementation f_0 */ }
      virtual void g() { cout << "g_0\n"; /* implementation g_0 */ }
      virtual void h() { cout << "h_0\n"; /* implementation h_0 */ }
  };

  struct f_1 : public virtual base {
      void f() override { cout << "f_1\n"; /* implementation f_1 */ }
  };

  struct g_1 : public virtual base {
      void g() override { cout << "g_1\n"; /* implementation g_1 */ }
  };

  struct h_1 : public virtual base {
      void h() override { cout << "h_1\n"; /* implementation h_1 */ }
  };

  struct h_2 : public virtual base {
      void h() override { cout << "h_2\n"; /* implementation h_2 */ }
  };


  struct W : public g_1  {
      // void g() override { /* implementation g_1 */ }
  };

  struct X : public g_1, h_1 {
      // void g() override { /* implementation g_1 */ }
      // void h() override { /* implementation h_1 */ }
  };

  struct Y : public f_1, h_1 {
      // void f() override { /* implementation f_1 */ }
      // void h() override { /* implementation h_1 */ }
  };

  struct Z : public f_1, h_2 {
      // void f() override { /* implementation f_1 */ }
      // void h() override { /* implementation h_2 */ }
  };

  int main() {

      cout << "\nW\n";
      W w;
      w.f();
      w.g();
      w.h();

      cout << "\nX\n";
      X x;
      x.f();
      x.g();
      x.h();

      cout << "\nY\n";
      Y y;
      y.f();
      y.g();
      y.h();

      cout << "\nZ\n";
      Z z;
      z.f();
      z.g();
      z.h();
  }
```

Output:

```
W
f_0
g_1
h_0

X
f_0
g_1
h_1

Y
f_1
g_0
h_1

Z
f_1
g_0
h_2
```